# Is it possible to perform a batch request to delete multiple objects in the C++ client library?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am looking at implementing a function to delete multiple objects in a Cloud Storage Bucket

```
void delete_objects(std::span<std::string> keys) {}
```

I would rather use a batch request to perform a singular request rather than plainly using `DeleteObject()` within a for loop as this would perform too many requests.

I have looked at the batch directory within the C++ client library:

```
auto batch_client = google::cloud::batch_v1::BatchServiceClient(google::cloud::batch_v1::MakeBatchServiceConnection());
```

However, I'm unsure how to format a batch request to delete multiple objects / if it is even possible in the C++ client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to remove multiple objects with a single RPC in the C++ SDK:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/batch#csharp-batch-requests

The `batch` directory includes the library to support [Cloud Batch](https://cloud.google.com/batch) a service to schedule and manage batch jobs. It has nothing to do with batched requests. Very little to do with GCS for that matter [^1]

FWIW, we are working on an asynchronous client to better support concurrent requests, but this is still experimental:

https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/storage/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage__experimental_1_1AsyncClient#classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage__experimental_1_1AsyncClient_1a2f93b11db073e8c0b40620e05af88a70

[^1]: You can attach GCS volumes to a batch job, but that seems irrelevant for this question.